# Can't navigate directly to URL Angular UI Router

Tags: angularjs, node.js, requirejs, angular-ui-router, pug

This is my router file: 

it's nested inside a require.js block and configured to work with Jade templates

```
define([
    './app',
    'angular.uirouter'
], function(app, angularUIRouter) {
    "use strict";

    // ROUTES
    app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        // loads url from the index
        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

        $stateProvider
            .state('dashboard', {
                url:'/dashboard',
                views: {
                    'core' : {
                        templateUrl: '/articles/dashboard'
                    }
                }
            }) 
    }]);
});
```

And this is my Express.js router file:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();

/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render('main', { 
        title: 'Express' 
    });
});

router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
    console.log("/dashboard requested");
});

router.get('/articles/:name', function (req, res) { 
    var name = req.params.name;
    res.render('articles/' + name);
});

module.exports = router;
```

When I go to localhost:3000/dashboard, it's making a GET request to the server.  How do I configure Angular UI Router to handle GET requests instead of the server?

Note: I can still go to localhost:3000/articles/dashboard and see the dashboard.  Also,

`a(ui-sref="dashboard")`

loads the dashboard correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Neither angular nor ui router can not handle server GET. Angular $locationProvider html5Mode solves only client-side setting - url does not contain # and location controls also path part in URL.

Html5 mode requires server side configuration. Every requests must return application entry point - usually index.html.

For example

```
router.get('/dashboard', function(req, res) {
  res.sendfile('path-to/index.html');
});
```

Comment: Any ideas on how to show the dashboard pager this way instead of "redirecting" the user to the homepage?